# create a product with combination of grouped and bundle product magento

Tags: magento, product

I want to create a new product with combination of bundle product and grouped product like in this link https://www.urbanladder.com/products/apollo-infinity-sofa?sku=FNSF51APMB30000SAAAA

Showing Choose a popular set (bundle product)

showing or Create Your Own Set(grouped product)

both are treated as one product

Is there any plugin to achieve this or can i do it from admin panel.Please help.

config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config>
    <modules>
        <Ajzele_CustomProduct>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Ajzele_CustomProduct>
    </modules>

    <global>
        <models>
            <customproduct>
                <class>Ajzele_CustomProduct_Model</class>       
            </customproduct>
        </models>    

        <resources>
            <customproduct_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Ajzele_CustomProduct</module>
                    <class>Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Setup</class>
                </setup>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_setup</use>
                </connection>
            </customproduct_setup>
        </resources>        

        <catalog>
            <product>
                <type>
                    <customproduct translate="label" module="catalog">
                        <label>Custom Product by Ajzele</label>
                        <model>customproduct/product_type_cp</model>
                        <is_qty>1</is_qty>
                        <index_data_retreiver>customproduct/catalogIndex_data_cp</index_data_retreiver>
                        <price_model>customproduct/product_type_grouped_price</price_model>
                        <composite>0</composite>
                    </customproduct>

                </type>
            </product>        
        </catalog>
    </global>  

    <adminhtml>
        <events>
            <catalog_product_new_action>
                <observers>
                    <customproduct_observer_catalog_product_new_action>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>customproduct/observer</class>
                        <method>hookIntoCatalogProductNewAction</method>
                    </customproduct_observer_catalog_product_new_action>
                </observers>
            </catalog_product_new_action>
            <catalog_product_edit_action>
                <observers>
                    <customproduct_observer_catalog_product_edit_action>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>customproduct/observer</class>
                        <method>hookIntoCatalogProductEditAction</method>
                    </customproduct_observer_catalog_product_edit_action>
                </observers>
            </catalog_product_edit_action>          
            <catalog_product_prepare_save>
                <observers>
                    <customproduct_observer_catalog_product_prepare_save>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>customproduct/observer</class>
                        <method>hookIntoCatalogProductPrepareSave</method>
                    </customproduct_observer_catalog_product_prepare_save>
                </observers>
            </catalog_product_prepare_save>
            <catalog_product_delete_before>
                <observers>
                    <customproduct_observer_catalog_product_delete_before>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>customproduct/observer</class>
                        <method>hookIntoCatalogProductDeleteBefore</method>
                    </customproduct_observer_catalog_product_delete_before>
                </observers>
            </catalog_product_delete_before>            
            <catalog_product_save_after>
                <observers>
                    <customproduct_observer_catalog_product_save_after>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>customproduct/observer</class>
                        <method>hookIntoCatalogProductSaveAfter</method>
                    </customproduct_observer_catalog_product_save_after>
                </observers>
            </catalog_product_save_after>
            <catalog_product_status_update>
                <observers>
                    <customproduct_observer_catalog_product_status_update>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>customproduct/observer</class>
                        <method>hookIntoCatalogProductStatusUpdate</method>
                    </customproduct_observer_catalog_product_status_update>
                </observers>
            </catalog_product_status_update>            




            <sales_order_item_save_after>
                <observers>
                    <customproduct_observer_sales_order_item_save_after>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>customproduct/observer</class>
                        <method>hookIntoSalesOrderItemSaveAfter</method>
                    </customproduct_observer_sales_order_item_save_after>
                </observers>
            </sales_order_item_save_after>
            <sales_order_save_before>
                <observers>
                    <customproduct_observer_sales_order_save_before>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>customproduct/observer</class>
                        <method>hookIntoSalesOrderSaveBefore</method>
                    </customproduct_observer_sales_order_save_before>
                </observers>
            </sales_order_save_before>            
            <sales_order_save_after>
                <observers>
                    <customproduct_observer_sales_order_save_after>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>customproduct/observer</class>
                        <method>hookIntoSalesOrderSaveAfter</method>
                    </customproduct_observer_sales_order_save_after>
                </observers>
            </sales_order_save_after>
            <catalogrule_before_apply>
                <observers>
                    <customproduct_observer_catalogrule_before_apply>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>customproduct/observer</class>
                        <method>hookIntoCatalogruleBeforeApply</method>
                    </customproduct_observer_catalogrule_before_apply>
                </observers>
            </catalogrule_before_apply>
            <catalogrule_after_apply>
                <observers>
                    <customproduct_observer_catalogrule_after_apply>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>customproduct/observer</class>
                        <method>hookIntoCatalogruleAfterApply</method>
                    </customproduct_observer_catalogrule_after_apply>
                </observers>
            </catalogrule_after_apply>
            <catalog_entity_attribute_save_after>
                <observers>
                    <customproduct_observer_catalog_entity_attribute_save_after>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>customproduct/observer</class>
                        <method>hookIntoCatalogEntityAttributeSaveAfter</method>
                    </customproduct_observer_catalog_entity_attribute_save_after>
                </observers>
            </catalog_entity_attribute_save_after>
            <catalog_product_delete_after_done>
                <observers>
                    <customproduct_observer_catalog_product_delete_after_done>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>customproduct/observer</class>
                        <method>hookIntoCatalogProductDeleteAfterDone</method>
                    </customproduct_observer_catalog_product_delete_after_done>
                </observers>
            </catalog_product_delete_after_done>

            <customer_login>
                <observers>
                    <customproduct_observer_customer_login>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>customproduct/observer</class>
                        <method>hookIntoCustomerLogin</method>
                    </customproduct_observer_customer_login>
                </observers>
            </customer_login>
            <customer_logout>
                <observers>
                    <customproduct_observer_customer_logout>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>customproduct/observer</class>
                        <method>hookIntoCustomerLogout</method>
                    </customproduct_observer_customer_logout>
                </observers>
            </customer_logout>
            <sales_quote_save_after>
                <observers>
                    <customproduct_observer_sales_quote_save_after>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>customproduct/observer</class>
                        <method>hookIntoSalesQuoteSaveAfter</method>
                    </customproduct_observer_sales_quote_save_after>
                </observers>
            </sales_quote_save_after>
            <catalog_product_collection_load_after>
                <observers>
                    <customproduct_observer_catalog_product_collection_load_after>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>customproduct/observer</class>
                        <method>hookIntoCatalogProductCollectionLoadAfter</method>
                    </customproduct_observer_catalog_product_collection_load_after>
                </observers>
            </catalog_product_collection_load_after>
        </events>
    </adminhtml>

</config>
```

Type.php

```
class Ajzele_CustomProduct_Model_Product_Type extends Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type_Abstract
{
    const TYPE_CP_PRODUCT = 'customproduct';
}
```

this give me simple custom product type.What should i add to get combination of bundle and grouped product.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: @Enigmativity if you know magento you should know that to add custom product type in magento you have to do programming.There you have add many php files and xml files by doing coding in them.If you dont know about specific thing how can you vote to close that thing.

Comment: Just because if requires programming it doesn't mean that this question is about programming. We're also not a code writing service. Please show us the code you're having difficulty with and then we can help you fixing it.

Comment: @Enigmativity please help.

Comment: I've retracted my close vote. You've got a good question now. I hope you get an answer.

Comment: @Enigmativity thanks bro